# Amcharts min and max value display

Tags: amcharts

I am using Amcharts to draw vaue and volume graph. Here i want
 to display min value and max value on each zoom and period selector.
 pls help me out.

sample code is below

```
 var changingEvent = AmCharts.addMovingAverage(chartConfig.dataSets[0], chartConfig.panels[0], 'value', {
        useDataSetColors: false,
        color: "#ccffcc",
        title: "Moving average"
    });
```

Full code is in this link

http://jsfiddle.net/TuLpK/115/